# How to make only Div scrollable instead of window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a set of 3 div elements scrollable by dragging the mouse. Currently, the window is scrolling instead of the divs. On changing the window.scrollTo function to $('.widgets).scrollTo the debugger returns an error without much information. What i would like is the div elements in grey to be scrollable without the scroll bar but by dragging the mouse vertically.

HTML:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="index.js"></script>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body class="overflowyhide">

<div id="header" class="overflowyhide">

</div>

<div id="body" class="overflowyhide">
    <div class="appcontainer">
        <div class="appcardser white">
            <p>App Card Ser</p>
            <div class="widgets" id="wone">WOne</div>
            <div class="widgets" id="wtwo">WTwo</div>
            <div class="widgets" id="wthree">WThree</div>
        </div>
        <div class="caui white">
        Caui
            <div id="widgetOne">
                WidgetOne
                <div class="closeCAUI">Close</div>
            </div>



        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
#header{
    outline: 1px solid red;
    background: black;
}

#body{
    outline: 1px solid blue;
    background: black;
}

body{

}

.white{
    color: white;
}

.overflowyhide{
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

#widgetOne{
    background: red;
    height: 50px;
}

.widgets{
    height: 400px;
    color: black;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: moz-none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

#wone{
    background: #dedede;

}

#wtwo{
    background: #9E9E9E;
}

#wthree{
    background: #828282;
}

.appcontainer{
     margin-right: 60px;
     margin-left: 60px;
     position: relative;
}

.appcardser{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    white-space: normal;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow:hidden; 
    transition:all 0.4s ease-in;
    z-index: 10;
}

.appcardser:hover{
    background: rgba(0,0,0,1);
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    transition:all 0.4s ease-in;
    white-space: normal;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow-y:scroll; 
    overflow-x:hidden;
    z-index: 10; 
}


.caui{
  position: absolute;
  height:350px;
  top:90%;
width: 100%;
left: 0%;
z-index: 100;
background-color: rgba(8,8,8,0.95);
transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.cauitrans{
  position: absolute;
  height:350px;
  top:0%;
width: 100%;
left: 0%;
z-index: 100;
-webkit-filter: blur(20px);
    -moz-filter: blur(20px);
    -o-filter: blur(20px);
    -ms-filter: blur(20px);
    filter: blur(20px);
transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.cauireal{
  position: absolute;
/*  height:350px;
*/  top:0%;
width: 100%;
left: 0%;
z-index: 100;
transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.cauismall{
  position: absolute;
  height:15px;
  width: 15px;
  top:92%;
  left:2%; 
  z-index: 100;
   border-radius: 50%;
 border:1px solid rgba(255,0,0,1);
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,1);
transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.cauibig{
    position: absolute;
    top:10%;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0%;
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: rgba(8,8,8,0.9);
    transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.contdisapper{
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.contdisapperani{
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


$('#header').height($(window).height()*0.1);
$('#body').height($(window).height()*0.9);

$('.appcontainer').width($(window).width()*0.55);
$('.appcardser').width($(window).width()*0.55);
$('.cauibig').height($(window).height()*0.8);
$('.caui').height($(window).height()*0.8);

$('.appcardser, .appcontainer').height($(window).height()*0.9);

// $('.clicktransform2').click(function() {
//        $('.caui').toggleClass('cauibig');
// });

$('.caui').click(function(){
    var heightOne = $('#widgetOne').height();
    var appContainerHeight = $('.appcontainer').height();

    if (heightOne >= appContainerHeight*0.1 && heightOne <= appContainerHeight*0.3){
        console.log("one");
        console.log(appContainerHeight*0.1);
        console.log(appContainerHeight*0.3);
        $('.caui').css({top: "80%"});
    } 
    else if (heightOne > appContainerHeight*0.3 && heightOne <= appContainerHeight*0.5){
        console.log("two");
        console.log(appContainerHeight*0.3);
        console.log(appContainerHeight*0.5);
        $('.caui').css({top: "60%"});
    }
    else if (heightOne > appContainerHeight*0.5 && heightOne <= appContainerHeight*0.7){
        console.log("three");
        console.log(appContainerHeight*0.5);
        console.log(appContainerHeight*0.7);
        $('.caui').css({top: "40%"});
    }
    else if (heightOne > appContainerHeight*0.7 && heightOne <= appContainerHeight*0.9){
        console.log("four");
        console.log(appContainerHeight*0.7);
        console.log(appContainerHeight*0.9);
        $('.caui').css({top: "20%"});
    }
    else {
        $('.caui').css({top: "10%"});
    }
});

$(document).on('click', '.closeCAUI', function(){
    $('.caui').css({top: "90%"});
});

// $('.closeCAUI').hover(function(){
//  $('.caui').css({top: "90%"});
// })

var xpos = 0;
var ypos = 0;
var drag = false;


window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){
    if (drag == true){
        //console.log("drag is true");
        newx = document.body.scrollLeft + (xpos - e.pageX);
        newy = document.body.scrollTop + (ypos - e.pageY);
        window.scrollTo(newx, newy);
        console.log(newx);
    }
});

window.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){
    drag = true;
    xpos = e.pageX;
    ypos = e.pageY;
});

window.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e){
    drag = false;
});

});
```

Jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/whw4h421/

Answer (score 1):

To scroll div you shuold use:

```
$('selector').scrollTop(ypos)
```

and

```
$('selector').scrollLeft(xpos)
```

[jQuery API Documentation .scrollTop()](http://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/)

Comment: I modified the JsFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/whw4h421/4/
The effect is very choppy compared to this example http://codepen.io/JTParrett/pen/rkofB?editors=011

Comment: You should use newy and newx instead of ypos and xpos in your example.
http://jsfiddle.net/whw4h421/6/

Comment: Also replace document.body.scrollLeft/Top with jQuery:
http://jsfiddle.net/whw4h421/5/

Comment: It seems to be working fine except for that fact that clicking outside the grey divs (clicking on the black background to the left of these divs) also triggers the scrolling. Any idea why this is?

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need JQuery/Javascript for that.

You can achieve what you want just using CSS.

You need to apply `overflow` and `position` properly to the parent and child div's.

[This demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5GCsJ/2471/) should show your solution.

Comment: How is this relevant? The demo does not even allow the user to scroll through the divs by dragging the mouse. The effect should be similar to this http://codepen.io/JTParrett/pen/rkofB?editors=011